# Programmatically upload a file from chrome extension. How to?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I need to upload a local file to a remote server from a chrome extension.  The extension extends chrome file browser and I'd like to invoke the upload when a user 'opens' a file with my extension.
I was hoping to use sockets APIs but just realised (hard way) that the APIs are available in apps only.

Could someone recommend a best practice/approach?

Thanks.

Comment: Just use PUT or POST, the same way you would upload from a web app.

Comment: Would you be able to provide an example?  I could handle uploads using a 'standard' way - i.e. HTML file input.  However, I need to initiate the upload from within a javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use HTTP PUT or POST, the same way you would upload from a web app. From Javascript, you do this with [`XMLHttpRequest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), specifying 'PUT' or 'POST' as the first argument to the `open()` method (whatever your server requires). MDN has [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file) (as they note, `sendAsBinary()` in the example should be changed to simply `send()`).

Comment: The example assumes that files were selected by a user.  That is, FileList and File object are created as a result of user interaction.  In my case, I get a file name from the file manager.  How can I upload it without creating a page with file input?

Comment: It shows how you upload a file. I thought you already knew how to get the file itself. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: I just realised that I have what I need.  The file browser gives me a File object which I should be able to use with PUT/POST as you described.